# Price should not be displayed

Tags: roomle

If the draft is saved and the link is copied, the price should NOT be displayed when the link is called up.

Where is the link assembled?
Can this be set during the integration in the website?

Comment: Please use English on Stack Overflow.

Comment: When i save configuration and want to send the Link to someone else, we don't want that the price is shown when the link opens the configurator.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is the following:

- in your configurator-settings set price service to false
- in the page where you embed the configurator override price service true so the prices are shown in your embedded page

Another (maybe more elegant) solution would be to provide a deeplink so you can link back to your embedding page. How this works is explained here: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#change-share-url

Comment: You can change configurator (Rubens) settings in the tenant settings (left menu) in the Rubens Admin interface. It's basically the same as the url params but as JSON. Those are then automatically applied when loading your configurator.

Comment: Hi tschoartschi,
did you see the "answer" below my colleague wrote? 

He wrote:
what do you mean by "in your configurator-settings set price service to false"? In roomle admin interface there is no setting to show/hide price - at least our customer does not have such an option and usePriceService is set to false.